# @MappedSuperclass and @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many, mappedsuperclass

I need association `@OneToMany` from Country to superclass `Place` (`@MappedSuperclass`). It could be bidirectional. I would need something like `@OneToAny`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Place {

    private String name;
    private Country country;

    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Country:

```
@Entity
   public class Country {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private List<Place> places;

   @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "place_type"), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @AnyMetaDef(idType = "integer", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
         @MetaValue(value = "C", targetEntity = City.class),
         @MetaValue(value = "R", targetEntity = Region.class) })
   @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
   //@JoinColumn(name="unnecessary") 
   //@OneToMany(mappedBy="country")  // if this, NullPointerException...
   public List<Place> getPlaces() {
      return places;
   }
//and rest of class
```

Without `@JoinColunm` there is an exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Any requires an explicit @JoinColumn(s): tour.spring.bc.model.vo.Country.places

In table City and Region is foreign key to table Country (Region.country_id, City.country_id) which is ok.
But I do NOT need foreign key in table Country to tables Region and City so I don't need `@JoinColum`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Any` doesn't make sense here since foreign key is at the `Place`s side and therefore it doesn't need additional meta column.

I'm not sure if it's possible to create a polymorphic relationship to `@MappedSuperclass`. However, you can try to declare `Place` as `@Entity @Inheritance(InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, it should produce the same database schema and allow polymorpic relationship.

Comment: There is a subtle but important difference in the database schema though. With `@MappedSuperclass`, each of the concrete subclasses of `Place` can have its own ID generator, whereas with `@Inheritance(InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, they all have to have the same. For example, instances of two different subtypes of `Place` can in the former case have the same ID number, but in the latter case they can't.